# How to return JSON from the ruby on rails getting started example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) really great tutorial. Now I would like to get the comments for a specific posting as JSON output.

Doing this for the posting is easy because it is just to call the .json. But how does it work with the comments?

Comment: Do you want the comments along with the posting, or each individual comment with it's own json responding route?

Comment: At least I would like both :-) The primary goal is to see the comments with it's own json responding route. Later on I would like to have the other way also.

Comment: I posted an answer, which does not include a great deal of actual code but should help you get things going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is mostly sans-code, but the ideas should at least set you in the right direction.

To provide comments with their own route, first set up a route for comments in your routes.rb file, then create a `show` method in the comments controller (similar to the way you set it up for a posting). In the `comments` controller `show` method, just render the comment the same way you do for the posting.

It is a bit easier to just include comments along with the posting when requesting the json output. In the `posts` controller `show` method, use `render :json => @posting.to_json(:include => :comment)` (substitute `@posting` for the name of the `Post` object you find in the `show` method).